# Oracle UNION have built- in sorting ability?

Tags: oracle, union

I've union the result of two subqueries.
1) Oracle's `UNION` sorts merged table in ascending order automatically?
2) I didn't specify alias M at the subquery. Is it legal?

```
CREATE TABLE T4 (
C0 VARCHAR2(10),
C1 VARCHAR2(10),
C2 NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abd',1);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abd',2);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abe',3);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abe',4);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','ace',5);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','ace',6);

INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abd',1);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abd',2);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abe',3);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abe',4);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','ace',5);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','ace',6);



SELECT ROWNUM,rr.C0,rr.M, rr.ss
FROM
(
SELECT C0,C1 M, SUM(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0, C1
UNION
SELECT C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)||'__'  , SUM(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)  --I didn't specify alias M. Is it legal?
) rr
ORDER BY rr.C0,rr.M ASC; --Without this, the same result shows. So, Oracle UNION sorts merged table in ascending order automatically?
```

Comment: No, without the `ORDER BY`, the order is not guaranteed. In oracle, alias for sub-query is not mandatory.

Comment: And for the second question - you need aliases only in first part of union. Off topic: you can get the same result using rollup `select c0, c1, substr(c1, 1, 1) m, sum(c2) ss from t4 group by c0, rollup(c1)`. No need to union data.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. Oracle uses internal mechanisms to union two queries and remove duplicates. This ***might*** include sorting as well, but it's fully up to optimizer to decide. So never rely on that. Provide an `ORDER BY` clause if you want the result to be sorted.
2. Yes, it's legal. Oracle names columns in the resulting dataset using the names of the first query in `UNION` statement.